# LINQ efficiency

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following LINQ statements:

```
var model = getModel();

// apptId is passed in, not the order, so get the related order id
var order = (model.getMyData
    .Where(x => x.ApptId == apptId)
    .Select(y => y.OrderId));

var orderId = 0;

var orderId = order.LastOrDefault();

// see if more than one appt is associated to the order
var apptOrders = (model.getMyData
    .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId)
    .Select(y => new { y.OrderId, y.AppointmentsId }));
```

This code works as expected, but I could not help but think that there is a more efficient way to accomplish the goal ( one call to the db ).

Is there a way to combine the two LINQ statements above into one?  For this question please assume I need to use LINQ.

Comment: `var orderId = 0;

        foreach (var item in order)
        {
            orderId = item;
        }` could be replaced with `var orderId = order.LastOrDefault();`.

Comment: @mjwills Nice catch.

Comment: @GuruStron Question updated.  getMyData is a table from the data store.

Comment: But if you have two or more orders with the same apptId how do you define which of these orders is the last one? Without an OrderBy you leave that decision to how your db retrieves the orders.

Comment: What is your ORM? Entity Framework?

Comment: @Markuzy Yes sadly we are still on EF4

Comment: @Steve apptids are unique.  An order can have more than one apptid associated to it.  And in my case, I only have an apptid, so I have to look up the order first and see if multiple apptids are associate.

Comment: What is `ApppointmentsId` and is it related to `ApptID`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy method to group all orders by OrderId. After applying LastOrDefault and ToList will give you the same result which you get from above code.

Here is a sample code:

```
 var apptOrders = model.getMyData
    .Where(x => x.ApptId == apptId)
    .GroupBy(s => s.OrderId)
    .LastOrDefault().ToList();
```

Comment: Initially I do not have an order id.

Comment: It is doing the same thing you are doing in your code. It is filtering orders by the given apptId, then grouping it by Order Id, and taking orders of the last orderId.

Comment: Ah, I missed the grouping by orderid.  I will test this out in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework can't translate `LastOrDefault`, but it can handle `Contains` with sub-queries, so lookup the `OrderId` as a query and filter the orders by that:

```
// apptId is passed in, not the order, so get the related order id
var orderId = model.getMyData
                   .Where(x => x.ApptId == apptId)
                   .Select(y => y.OrderId);

// see if more than one appt is associated to the order
var apptOrders = model.getMyData
                      .Where(a => orderId.Contains(a.OrderId))
                      .Select(a => a.ApptId);
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like this is all you need:

```
var apptOrders =
    model
        .getMyData
        .Where(x => x.ApptId == apptId)
        .Select(y => new { y.OrderId, y.AppointmentsId });
```

Comment: No, I need all those who share the same orderid.  I don't have the orderid accessable at this point, which is why I am looking it up first.

Comment: @Neo - Yes, but you are doing that via the `ApptId`. This still looks equivalent to me based on the code in your question.

Comment: Your answer assumes all of the data with a particular `ApptId` also have all the same `OrderId`, I highly doubt that's the case